# android using cursorloader instead of managedQuery

Tags: android

I can use a managedQuery like this:

```
Activity a = (Activity) context;
cursor = a.managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

And once I do, I have a cursor that I can step through however I want.

However, using a CursorLoader, when a new CursorLoader is created the onCreateLoader call back method is called.  The onCreateLoader call back returns a CursorLoader.  How do I get a reference to the cursor so I can step though it, as in managedCursor.

I missing the boat here, appreciate any direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also implement onLoadFinished, this method gives you the Cursor when the asynchronous load has finished

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
   myadapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}
```